# Laravel 1-N relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm starting my first Laravel project. I set up and tested all the relationships between tables and all of them look fine but one 1-N relationship. I cannot find the error, could you please help me?

Tables:

`User:
*id
*username`

Feeling:

`*id
*name
*user (it points to User:id)`

**Class User**

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'User';

    public function feelings() {
        return $this->hasMany('Feeling', 'user');
    }
}
```

**Class Feeling**

```
class Feeling extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'Feeling';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','user');
    }
}
```

If I execute:

```
$feeling = Feeling::find(1);
echo($feeling->user->username);
```

I get an error "Trying to get property of non-object".

If I execute

```
$feeling = Feeling::find(1);
```

It prints the Json array of the feeling object and if I execute

```
$feeling = Feeling::find(1);
echo($feeling->user);
```

It prints "1". So I'm getting the user ID of the database, but not the user object. I would like to get the user object instead.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

Everything is fine but you have used `user` as your local key and that's why the confusion because, when you call `$feeling->user` the magic method `__get()` is called which is  available in the `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent` and it; as given below:

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```

The `getAttribute()` method looks several places for the key and sequentially it looks into the `Model` itself at first and then looks into the relationship array and then at last checks if the key for examaple in your case `user` exists as a method in the `Model` which is `Feeling` in your case, then it gets the related model and finds the key value.

Hence, your `Feeling` has a field as `user` so before it goes to the related model it just finds the field in current `Model`'s attributes so it thinks that, `user` field has been requested for and you get the numeric `id` instead if related model instance.

### Solution:

Solution is pretty simple, change the related field name (`user`) to anything else, better is `user_id` but you are free to use anything but make sure that doesn't create any further confusions. So, if you change it to `user_id` then make changes to your both models, for example:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
```

But, if you use `user_id` then you may omit the second argument from both model's relationship method, so you may write:

```
// Feeling
return $this->belongsTo('User');

// User
return $this->hasMany('Feeling');
```

Comment: Yes! It worked, I only had to rename the database field. Thank you so much for your help!